# Decode a base64 string in golang

Tags: go, base64

I have this string  :

```
MTk6MTQ4MjMxOTY0MDo1NDU=
```

And i tried to decode it :

```
cookie_value = "MTk6MTQ4MjMxOTY0MDo1NDU="
sDec, _  := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(cookie_value)
Info.Println(sDec)
```

but it gives me that :

```
INFO: 2016/12/21 12:27:20 ApiRender.go:158: [49 57 58 49 52 56 50 51 49 57 54 52 48 58 53 52 53]
```

if you have any idea how to decode it properly

thanks and regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be very hard:

```
Info.Println(string(sDec))
```